# Null pointer exception while loading applet

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, applet

Error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at sun.plugin2.applet.JNLP2Manager.getAppInfo(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

```html
<script src="http://java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>  
    <script>  
        var attributes = {  
            code:       "com.futronictech.ScanDemoJApplet.class",  
            archive:    "FtrScanApplet.jar",  
            width:      400,  
            height:     500  
        };  
        var parameters = {jnlp_href:"launch.jnlp"};   
        var version = "1.6";   
       deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, version);  
    </script>  
    <!-- Or use the following applet element to launch the applet using jnlp_href -->  
   <!--  <applet width="400" height="500">  
        <param name="jnlp_href" value="launch.jnlp"/>  
    </applet> -->
```

I have added `FtrScanApplet.jar` in application root directory itself. I have updated Java, changed security of java and also cleared cache but no result.
Kindly help me to sort out this issue.

Comment: Which (exact) java version are you using? Are you using the 32 or the 64 Bit version?

Comment: I'm getting the same thing for an applet launched from a similar jnlp. It works fine in JRE 7u71, but in 8u25 in both IE11 and FireFox 34 I get an identical stack trace.

In java console: network: Cache entry not found [url: http://localhost:8080/launch.jnlp, version: null]